# Event raising in another thread

Tags: .net, multithreading

I want to implement the following logic:

```
  private static AutoResetEvent _autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     var someObjectInstance = new SomeObject();
     someObjectInstance.SomeEvent += SomeEventHandler;
     _autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
     //...
  }

  static void SomeEventHandler()
  {
     _autoResetEvent.Set();
  }
```

So the Main method should wait till SomeEvent is called the first time. As I understand _autoResetEvent.WaitOne blocks the thread so SomeEvent should be raised in another thread. But how can I guarantee it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want the event to be raised from another thread? The following code would do just that.

```
public class Program
{
  private static AutoResetEvent _autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false); 

  static void Main(string[] args) 
  { 
    var someObjectInstance = new SomeObject(); 
    someObjectInstance.SomeEvent += SomeEventHandler;
    var thread = new Thread(
      () =>
      {
        someObjectInstance.DoSomethingThatRaisesSomeEvent();
      });
    thread.Start();
    _autoResetEvent.WaitOne(); 
    //... 
  } 

  static void SomeEventHandler() 
  { 
    _autoResetEvent.Set(); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the main thread will reach `_autoResetEvent.WaitOne()`, it will be blocked until that Event object will be signaled. If the `AutoResetEvent` object never gets signaled, then the thread that waits on `WaitOne()` will block indefinitely (assuming no one throws an `InterruptException` on the main thread, and no timeout value was passed to the `WaitOne()` method).